# Variable comparison problem in PHP

Tags: php, comparison-operators

I'm trying to determine whether or not two strings match, and even though when I print them out, they're identical, it still says they don't match.  I tried to cast them both as strings, and I tried using '===' instead of '==', but neither solved the problem...

```
   if(preg_match("#^Availability:#", $test)) {
    //just to note: $test = "Availability: Lorem Ipsum";

    $nid = 1;
    $prep = explode("Availability:", $test);

    $orig = node_load($nid);

    print $prep[1];  //Prints Lorem Ipsum
    print($orig->title); //Prints Lorem Ipsum

    if((string)$orig->title == (string)$prep[1]) { 
      print 'ok'; 
    } else { 
      print 'nope'; //Always prints nope
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Probably a line break / white space issue. Can you do a `trim()` on both values and see if they match then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$test has a space after `Availability`: maybe you must trim strings before comporation. like that

```
if(trim($orig->title) == trim($prep[1]))
```

Comment: Yes, that was it... Thank you... (I can't accept for seven more minutes, but I will!)

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's almost certain to be spaces on the begining and/or end of your strings.

For example, you are doing `explode("Availability:",$test);`, but your string has a space after 'Availability:', before 'Lorum', so `$prep[1]` will be equal to ' Lorum Ipsum' - with a leading space.

Either change your `explode()` call, or use `trim()` in your comparisons.